# Is possible to implement this op-amp split power supply design?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, switch-mode-power-supply

[image]

Hi all, I have a op-amp charge pump circuit that could produce up to 3A 1000Hz AC current regardless of load. This current is used to test a battery (V1 in the image). The weird part is that I have limited choice for op-amp power supply design and I have to design a power supply that take power from the very battery that I want to pump a current into. Is there a solution to this kind of circuit loop?

I have simulate the op-amp circuit with external supply and the results show that the op-amp only load a 10 mA current from +-30V rail. The op-amp part also worked with real PCB board supplied by an external power source.

The image above is kind of irrelevant because if I connect the common ground of +-30V to the op-amp circuit ground then the isolated design is in vain. Can I use synchronous power supply in this case?

Comment: Your op amp is inputted with 200mV ac? With this input it produce a constant current of DC 3Amp? And you charge the battery (V1) using 3 Amps? What battery is that? A lithium ion? I see many inconsistencies here....

Comment: Output current is also an AC current. The "battery" is in fact a string of 6 2V cells in series (lead acid, 200 Ah each).

Comment: I see no rectifier in your schematic.

Comment: There's no need for a rectifier, the output current is intended to test the battery for only few seconds.

Comment: "I have to design a power supply that take power from the very battery that I want to pump a current into." - this is not going to work.

Comment: look like a free energy type of project...

Comment: @MathieuL That's what I was thinking too... But I'm afraid it is actually free *wasted* energy.

Comment: @HacLe If you want to simulate a battery, a 12V source in LT spice isn't going to work. A 12V ideal source in spice can source infinite amounts of current, A 12V battery's voltage drops when you source high currents AND there is a current limit. The current that you put back into the battery is going to affect the voltage of the battery and it is also going to make a nice feedback loop. And power feedback loops can be dangerous because they burn up parts if they are unstable. If you don't understand controls and feedback, you need a redesign

Answer (score 2):

There is a BIG PROBLEM with your scheme.
It contravenes the laws of thermodynamics. You are charging a battery from itself. If your circuit feeds 3 A to the battery but draws 3.5 A (due to inefficiencies in the inverter) then the net result is that you are drawing 0.5 A from the battery. You will never put any charge into it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEodX5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A much more efficient battery self charger. This circuit doesn't actually charge the battery but doesn't discharge it either so it would be much better than the proposal in the question.*

> I have a op-amp charge pump circuit that could produce up to 3A current regardless of load.

That statement means that the output voltage is able to go to infinity to drive a very high resistance load. That is clearly nonsense.

Where did you find an opamp with 3A output as a matter of interest?

Comment: Power op amp capable up to 10Amps are available.

Comment: I know, but there's no part number on the schematic and I'm wondering if the OP knows.

Comment: I know it IS weird but the fact that U1 (OPA544) only load 10 mA from each of the +-30V allows me to imagine such a thing.                                                                                                 Well not infinitely but it can put out a 3A current even when the output is shorted to ground for a decent period of time. The op-amp is a TI OPA544T.

Comment: This is NOT a battery charger, this is battery test current generator. The current only go through the battery for a short time.

Comment: (1) The 10 mA load is probably the quiescent current when output current is zero. The output current has to come from somewhere so it will come from the opamp positive supply and will be 3A. You can't get energy for free. (2) "_The current only go through the battery for a short time._" The circuit can only _draw_ current from the battery. (3) Edit your original question to state what you are trying to achieve. Are you testing the battery response to _charging_ or to _draining_?

Comment: I have simulated the circuit with external power supply and 10mA is exactly the load current of the op-amp. The op-amp output current is AC so no power is taken from the battery itself because the op-amp is both a source and a sink in a period of the test current.

Comment: It can't be unless the output current is zero or if you are taking a _DC_ reading which averages out the AC to zero.

Comment: If you have a simulation software in your hand you could try simulating that op-amp circuit with +-30V rails and then witness the "magic" unfolding before your eyes. I have produced a real PCB board for the circuit and it worked (with external power supply ofcourse).

Comment: You are telling me that I can get 3 A out of an amplifier with 10 mA in on the amplifier power rails. This is not possible. It's not magic. It's an error somewhere in your simulation and measurements. Put an ammeter in the supply lines and see what's happening.